# What does the service health for GCP's Virtual Private Cloud (VPC) cover? (https://status.cloud.google.com/regional/americas)

Tags: google-cloud-platform

In the Google Cloud Service Health console (https://status.cloud.google.com/regional/americas) Virtual Private Cloud is shown to not be available in some regions.

Does this mean VPC is not supported in the region or is this health status just inter-regional VPC connections (that this region doesn't support global or external V2 connections)?